# Travelling Salesman Variation

Tags: operations-research

Is there a name for this variation and a recommended algorithm for solving this problem:

- You have a large boat with many leaks on it.
- As soon as you patch a leak, it resets, and slowly begins leaking again gradually over time at a higher and higher flow rate.
- Each leak has a varying rate at which it increases flow, but you know what this rate is for each leak.
- You can instantly patch a leak by visiting it, but it takes you time to move between leaks.

Over the course of a day, how can you minimize the amount of water let into your boat?

Comment: Nice problem! I am not sure it is a TSP variation, as you don't have to visit each leak, and you can visit the same leak more than once if necessary. Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: Yeah it has similar features to TSP (traversing a network), but is not the same - not even the same class of problem perhaps. OR is not my field, so I was trying to find out if this is a common problem.

Comment: It's a real problem (just not a common problem) that comes from the mining industry. It's about keeping components in a system serviced when you have limited resources available.